# Trouble updating SQL table in JDBC

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to update a SQL table where the workout_date is my primary key. I'm getting an error message about the date format. I've tried everything I can think of but still stuck. Here's the relevant code:

```
public static Boolean updateWorkout(String date, float totalWorkout, float walkTime,
                                        float runTime, float distance, float average, String rate,
                                        Integer workoutID) throws SQLException {
        Locale loc = new Locale("en", "US");


        PreparedStatement sqlCommand = DBConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE " +
                "progress_table SET totalTime=?, timeWalking=?, timeRunning=?, totalDistance=?, " +
                "avgPace=?, workoutRating=?, workoutID=? WHERE workout_date=?");
        sqlCommand.setString(1, date);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(2, totalWorkout);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(3, walkTime);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(4, runTime);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(5, distance);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(6, average);
        sqlCommand.setString(7, rate);
        sqlCommand.setInt(8, workoutID);

        try {
            sqlCommand.executeUpdate();
            sqlCommand.close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            sqlCommand.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And my error message:

````
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '10' for column 'workout_date' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031)
    at Model.Progress.updateWorkout(Progress.java:121)
    at Controller.editView.saveRun(editView.java:157)```

Insights will be greatly appreciated!

Edit to add a sample of the data I'm working with. I'm testing with the last line.
[![Data][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lqh5.png
````

Comment: It appears you are trying to set date = 10 per your error message. What are the values of your parameters that are being passed into your function?

Comment: It's drawing the value from a selected line in the table. In this particular case. I think the workoutID is set to 10. But why would it be trying to save that to the date?

Comment: Why are you using a workout date as a primary key? Primary keys should be unique to a record. Even as a timestamp you'd be hardpressed to sell it as unique. Please update your OP with the schema/ddl for the table you are trying to insert into along with at least one record.of data from that table.

Comment: your workout I'd is your last param being passed in and is hitting the workout date field instead. Workout_id is 7.

Comment: That's the item in the dataset most likely to be unique where most of the rest of it can repeat. Thanks, I'll try playing with the params and see if that helps.

Comment: I've provided an answer below for your reference and some additional clarity if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are not in order:

```java
PreparedStatement sqlCommand = DBConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE " +
                "progress_table SET totalTime=?, timeWalking=?, timeRunning=?, totalDistance=?, " +
                "avgPace=?, workoutRating=?, workoutID=? WHERE workout_date=?");
     
        sqlCommand.setFloat(1, totalWorkout);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(2, walkTime);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(3, runTime);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(4, distance);
        sqlCommand.setFloat(5, average);
        sqlCommand.setString(6, rate);
        sqlCommand.setInt(7, workoutID);
        sqlCommand.setString(8, date);
```

Additionally, if you are assigning a primary key to a table, it MUST be unique rather than most likely to be. Primary keys indicate that no matter what, this value references this row in this table and no other. Consider adding a true auto incrementing primary key or setting up a clustered index/combination key. A great option would be a combination of workout_date and workout_id for example.